# Create Asymmetric key in SQL using a variable password (from stored procedure)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, encryption, sql-server-2014

```
create procedure SP_INS_PUBLIC_NHANVIEN  
    @manv varchar(20),
    @hoten nvarchar(100),
    @email varchar(20),
    @luongcb varbinary ,
    @tendn nvarchar(100),
    @mk varchar

as 
    create asymmetric key mahoaluongi
        with algorithm = RSA_512
        encryption by password = @mk
    insert into nhanvien values (@manv,@hoten,@email,ENCRYPTBYASYMKEY(mahoaluongi,@luongcb),@tendn,HASHBYTES('SHA1',@mk),@manv)
    drop asymmetric key mahoaluongi
go
```

I want to create a new asymmetric key with new  password each time, passed from the parameter of stored procedure.
I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near @mk. expecting STRING or TEXT_LEX.

But it was impossible to convert from varchar to STRING using `cast` or `convert`.

I'm using SQL server 2014

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: it's not a good idea to create a new asymmetric key every time you insert a new record into `nhanvien` and then dropping it. How will you decrypt the data afterwards?

Comment: @ughai I use _mk as a password to log in and encrypt another column. Therefore I need to encrypt it inside the stored procedure

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that using Exec Command as following query:

```
create procedure SP_INS_PUBLIC_NHANVIEN  
    @manv varchar(20),
    @hoten nvarchar(100),
    @email varchar(20),
    @luongcb varbinary ,
    @tendn nvarchar(100),
    @mk varchar

as 
    DECLARE @C NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
    'create asymmetric key mahoaluongi
        with algorithm = RSA_512
        encryption by password = '''+@mk+''''
    EXEC(@C)
    insert into nhanvien values (@manv,@hoten,@email,ENCRYPTBYASYMKEY(ASYMKEY_ID('mahoaluongi'),@luongcb),@tendn,HASHBYTES('SHA1',@mk),@manv)
    Exec('drop asymmetric key mahoaluongi')
```

Comment: but it still has 'invalid column name name mahoaluongi' at encryptbyasymkey function

Comment: @QuangVĩnhHà. I changed my code. please check again.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SP_INS_ENCRYPTED_KEY @name VARCHAR(20)
    ,@age INT
    ,@city VARCHAR(20)
    ,@mk VARCHAR(20)
AS
CREATE asymmetric KEY mahoaluongi
    WITH algorithm = RSA_512 ENCRYPTION BY password = N'@mk'

INSERT INTO Emp@236186
VALUES (
    @name
    ,@age
    ,ENCRYPTBYASYMKEY(AsymKey_ID('mahoaluongi'), @city)
    )

DROP asymmetric KEY mahoaluongi
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_INS_PUBLIC_NHANVIEN 
    @MANV   VARCHAR(20) ,
    @HOTEN  NVARCHAR(100),
    @EMAIL  VARCHAR (20),
    @LUONGCB    VARCHAR(100),
    @TENDN  NVARCHAR(100),
    @MK     VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
    IF ASYMKEY_ID(@MANV) IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = 'CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY '  + QUOTENAME(@MANV) + ' ' +
                 'WITH ALGORITHM = RSA_2048 ' + 
                 'ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = ' + QUOTENAME(@MK , NCHAR(39))
        EXEC (@SQL)
    END

    DECLARE @MATKHAU_SHA1 VARBINARY(MAX);
    SET @MATKHAU_SHA1 = CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),HASHBYTES('SHA1', @MK));

    DECLARE @LUONG_RSA512 VARBINARY(MAX);
    SET @LUONG_RSA512 = ENCRYPTBYASYMKEY(ASYMKEY_ID(@MANV), @LUONGCB);

    DECLARE @PUBKEY NVARCHAR(20);
    SELECT @PUBKEY = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20),@MANV);

    INSERT INTO DBO.NHANVIEN
    VALUES (@MANV, @HOTEN, @EMAIL, ENCRYPTBYASYMKEY(ASYMKEY_ID(@MANV), @LUONGCB), @TENDN, @MATKHAU_SHA1,@PUBKEY);
END
GO
```

Comment: Please consider adding a description to the code so that we would understand WHY it solves the op's issue